# Tag page that displays specific posts

Tags: posts, templates, tags

How would I go about coding a generic tag.php page that displays all the posts with a specific tag?

For example, if I navigate to example.com/tag/your-tag, it should display all posts with the tag "your tag".

Comment: You could start by looking at how [Twenty Fourteen does it](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/tag.php)

Answer (score 0):

Create tag.php & save it in your theme directory. This is a default behavior of wordpress. So you don't have to struggle with it.

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) :

        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            // Do your stuff here such as below
            the_title();
            the_content();

        endwhile;
    else:
        echo 'No Post Found';
    endif;
?>
```